# Нюансы static в функциях

Tags: c++, c, рекурсия, static

Как добиться приоритета для static переменной в операциях при рекурсии?

```
int sumOfOdds(int n)
{
    static int sum = -1; 
    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }   
    sum += 2;
    return sum + sumOfOdds(n - 1); 
}
```

Здесь выходит, что сначала достаётся результат из `sumOfOdds()`, и только затем считывается `sum`, но, т.к. `sum` изменяется при каждом вызове, считывается не то. Скобки не помогают, приходится делать что-то такое:

```
int _ = sum;
return _ + sumOfOdds(n - 1);
```

Я уверен, что это можно сделать более красиво

Comment: А что вы, собственно, хотите получить?... И почему именно `static`?

Comment: @Harry эта функция просто считает сумму нечётных чисел, получая на вход их количество. Я знаю, что есть миллиард других способов это сделать, но мне здесь важна именно красота и краткость. Такой у меня досуг :)

Comment: Так происходит, потому что операция сложения не является точкой следования, поэтому порядок вычисления операндов является unspecified behavior.

Comment: @КириллМалышев т.е. ничего поделать с этим нельзя?

Comment: Может, какие-то конкретные компиляторы дают какие-то гарантии, но я ничего такого не нашёл. И вы ведь понимаете, что, используя static-переменную, вы делаете одноразовую функцию? При повторном вызове с теми же аргументами результат будет другой.

Comment: @КириллМалышев да, спасибо, я это знаю

Answer (score 0):

Типа такого?

```
int sumOfOdds(int n, int sum = -1)
{
    if (n <= 0) return 0;
    sum += 2;
    return sum + sumOfOdds(n - 1, sum); 
}
```

или

```
int sumOfOdds(int n, int sum = 1)
{
    return n <= 0 ? 0 : sum + sumOfOdds(n - 1, sum+2);
}
```

или даже

```
int sumOfOdds(int n) { return (n<=0) ? 0 : 2*n-1+sumOfOdds(n-1); }
```

А без рекурсии, `n*n` - религия позволяет? :)

Comment: да, я так и хотел сделать, если не будет чего-то получше

Comment: про квадрат я и не слышал. Интересное явление

Comment: Забавно... http://mathemlib.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000016/st044.shtml или, скажем, https://forany.xyz/t-34 Странно, странно. Я думал, вы просто хотите с рекурсией поиграться...

Comment: Если захотите еще какие ряды посчитать... http://www.math24.ru/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8B.html

Comment: ухх.. как же мне часто не хватает таких визуальных объяснений. Спасибо! С рекурсией, конечно, тоже интересно

Answer (score 0):

```
int sumOfOdds(int n)
{
    static int sum = 1;
    if (n > 0) {
        sum += 2;
        sumOfOdds(n - 1);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: нет, это так не работает, но спасибо за попытку

Comment: работает, не работает... Я не знаю что вам нужно, чтобы выполняла функция, я лишь прочитал вопрос и ответил

Answer (score 0):

К чему сложности со static и рекурсией? Тут же простая арифметическая прогрессия

```
constexpr int sum_odds(int num)
{
    return num * (num + 1) - num;
}
```

Comment: А просто `num*num` - это таки слишком просто? :)